# Как корректно разрезать и соединить видео ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

У меня есть видео, длительностью 10 секунд (original_video.mp4).

Разделяю видео на 2 видеофайла

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:05 -i original_video.mp4 -c copy cut_0.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:10 -i original_video.mp4 -c copy cut_1.mp4
```

Объединяю видео

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i join_video_filelist.txt -c copy join_video.mp4
```

join_video_filelist.txt

```
file 'cut_0.mp4'
file 'cut_1.mp4'
```

В результате, в объединенном видео, "на стыке" 4 - 5 секунды пропадает звук. Пропадает на секунду и потом снова появляется. Почему это происходит и как это исправить?
Как корректно разрезать и соединить видео ffmpeg?

Comment: Вероятно из-за того, что обрезка при такой команде вырезания неточная...

Answer (score 2):

Без перекодирования видео ffmpeg режет видео по размеру блока, по ключевому кадру. А у звука размер блока меньше и режется он по отметке времени.

Попробуй найти ключевой кадр рядом с нужным отрезком [тамким кодом](https://superuser.com/a/554679/239779):

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type -v quiet in.mp4 | 
awk -F= ' 
  /pict_type=/ { if (index($2, "I")) { i=1; } else { i=0; } } 
  /pkt_pts_time/ { if (i && ($2 >= $INTERVAL)) print $2; }  
' | head -n 1
```

[Вычти из получившигося немного](https://superuser.com/a/1484728/239779) чтоб ffmpeg не резанул по следующему кейфрейму вместо нужного.

Если резать нужно точно, то только перекодирование.

Comment: Я не против перекодирования, если результат будет достаточно качественным. Как можно корректно разрезать и соединить видео с перекодированием?

Comment: укажи кодек вместо -c copy

Comment: Режу 
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:05 -i original_video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 cut_0.mp4 

Соединяю 
ffmpeg -f concat -i join_video_filelist.txt -vcodec libx264 join_video.mp4

Чуть лучше, звук пропадает на пол секунды. Но надо чтобы звук не пропадал вообще.

Comment: Тогда звуковую дорожку в отдельный файл. Склей отдельно и надожи обратно